# Fetch the original name of vector variable passed to a custom function

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe

My problem is best understood after reading the R script:

```
plotHistogram <- function(data, x, binw=0.30, color=FALSE, density=FALSE, h=10, w=10) {

    require(ggplot2)
    # data$x <- as.numeric(x)
    
    plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x)) 
    
    if(density & color) {
      plot <- plot + geom_density(fill="blue", aes(alpha=0.2))
    } else if (density) {
      plot <- plot + geom_density()
    } else if (color) {
      plot <- plot + 
        geom_histogram(binwidth=binw, aes(y=..density.., fill=..count..)) +
        scale_fill_gradient("Count", low="purple", high="red")
    } else {
      plot <- plot + geom_histogram(binwidth=binw, aes(y=..density.., fill=..count..))
    }
    
    ggsave(file="histo_plot.svg", plot=plot, height=h, width=w)
    
    return(plot)
}
```

Notice the commented line. Normally I have to use this to get ggplot to recognize that `x` belongs to `data`. This is a hack. My intent is to plot the name of whatever series is input as `x`.  I'm not sure how to do this because as far as I can tell, I have to store the column to be visualized in some variable, but that variable renames the vector, so there's no good way to find the original name in the data.frame.

I'm sure I'm overlooking a simple solution.

#### Edit:  Concretely expressed problem

Suppose I did the following:

```
plotHistogram(economics, economics$psavert)
```

This would result in either an error, or undesired result. If I uncomment that line, a x-axis label "x" is drawn, when what I really want is "psavert".

Comment: So you have a dataframe `data` with an element `data$x` ?  Or are you trying to add `x` to the dataframe? If you're just trying to get the name you input to the function, use `nameit<-deparse(substitute(x))`

Comment: Does `data[[deparse(substitute(x))]] <- as.numeric(x)` work?

Comment: I have dataframe `data`, it does not necessarily have `data$x`; rather, `x` is some vector within `data` that the user specifies to plot. If there's a better way of doing this, I'm open to suggestions.

The input vector `x` has some name in `data`, such as `economics$psavert`; I'd like to retrieve the original name.

Comment: unfortunately, the suggested code has not worked for me.

OP updated with a concrete example.

Comment: Take it a step at a time. Play with `deparse(subsitute(x))` until you're satisfied you can get a character string inside your function corresponding to the input variable name -- without doing any `ggplot` work. Once you've got that going, just use that string as your xlabel. Example:  `foo <- function (x) { xname<-deparse(substitute(x)); return(xname)}
bar<-1:5
(foo(bar))`